# Is it possible to configure dependencies in Azkaban to start a job after completion of either Job A or Job B, without requiring both of them to finish

Tags: data-pipeline, azkaban

I have a scenario where I have three jobs in my Azkaban workflow. I want to ensure that Job C starts only after the completion of either Job A or Job B. It doesn't matter which of the two jobs finishes first; as soon as either Job A or Job B completes, Job C should start its execution.

Is there a way to achieve this kind of dependency management in Azkaban? I have reviewed the Azkaban documentation, but I couldn't find a direct solution for handling this specific requirement.

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions.